# Trigger if Cell date Value is between now and in 24 hours. (Cdate.value)

Tags: vba, excel, date

I'm using Excel 2010 and writing a VBA script that needs to do something if the value is a Cell is between now and in 24 hours. I've looked through dozens of topic and couldn't find a way to efficiently do this.

Here are a few things you need to know.

The script looks for the value (Due Date) in a formula range:

```
Set FormulaRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tasks").Range("F5:F35")
On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
```

Let's say that F5 has the following value:

> 3/9/2016  9:50:00 AM

I am then trying to ask it to do "MyMsg = SentMsg" if the value in range F5:F35 is equal to now or in 24 hours.

*Below are a few ways I tried it, and have been unsuccessful at doing so.*

**1.** Doesn't work as it does not consider hours and minutes. It does trigger if the date is tomorrow though, but I need it to check for 24 hours, not +1 day).:

```
If DateValue(CDate(.Value)) >= Date And DateValue(CDate(.Value)) <= (Date + 1) Then
```

**2.** Then I tried to Round Down Now() to the last minute (and adding 1440 minutes for a full day) as the script autoruns itself every minute to check for trigger dates using:

```
If DateValue(CDate(.Value)) >= Date And DateValue(CDate(.Value)) <= ((Round(Now * 1440, 0) +1440) / 1440) Then
```

***2. Doesn't work as it triggers even if there are more than 24 hours, but doesn't if there is more than 30 hours? (This confuses me). This might be due to me using >= Date? I need to make sure it does send a reminder between Today's 0:00 AM and now + 24 hours.***

**3.**  I also tried to use the following but the result is the same as number 2:

```
If DateValue(CDate(.Value)) >= Date And DateValue(CDate(.Value)) <= (Now + TimeSerial(24, 0, 0)) Then
```

Am I overthinking this? Is there a easier, simpler way to do this, and if not. What am I doing wrong?

I believe one of the problem is that I can't use between Now and Now + something. Because the script removes the trigger if it is past Now(), so it really has to be a general date and now + time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I'm completely stuck there.

Thanks,
Francis M.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for: **between** now and 24 hours from now, or **either** now **or** 24 hours from now? If the former, then just check for greater than now and less than now + 1.

Comment: I would say **between** now and 24 hours from now. The script sends me email reminder when a task nears due date. I want the script to trigger when there is less than 24 hours left before the Date and Time of the due date is reached. So anywhere from **From Today (date without time) to 23 hours and 59 minutes from now**

Comment: Then it seems you want: `FormulaCell.Value >= Date and FormulaCell.Value < (Now + 1)`

Comment: That's what I first thought too. But my time right now is **03/08/2016 12:01 **PM. I set the cell value at **03/09/2016 9:50 PM** and the script triggers. While its limit should be **03/09/2016 12:01 PM**

Comment: Are you sure your cells contain real date/time values and not plain text?

Comment: It is formatted as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm, if it is what you mean. I manually write the date and time for the due date.

Comment: If you change the number format does the displayed value change? (That looks like mm/DD rather than dd/mm to me?)

Comment: Nevermind that, I had forgotten to switch to FormulaCell.Value.... Brainfart right here. Thanks a lot Rory! Everything's working fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible ways to add 24 hours to the current DateTime (i.e. `Now`) in Excel VBA; code snippet below demonstrates the use of these functions and also includes a sample `IF` check based on the condition that the date value in cell "A3" is between `Now` and (`Now`+24hrs):

```
Sub Add24h()
    ' one possible solution to add 24 hrs
    Range("A1").Value = Now + TimeSerial(24, 0, 0)

    ' another possible solution to add 24 hrs
    Range("A2") = DateAdd("h", 24, Now)

    'sample logical statement to check if the value is in between two of dates
    If (Range("A3") >= Now And Range("A3") <= (Now + TimeSerial(24, 0, 0))) Then
    ' place you code here
    End If

End Sub
```

The same functionality could be achieved by using Excel Worksheet functions, like shown below:

```
=IF(AND(A3>=NOW(),A3<=NOW()+1),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks for your time :) The problem in my scenario with >= Now is that I need the check to be and remain positive from the beginning of the day, for the whole day. And as above, using the TimeSerial + 24 triggers the script even if there is a difference greater than 24 hours :(  My time right now is **03/08/2016 12:06 **PM. I set the cell value at **03/09/2016 9:50 PM** and the script triggers. While its limit should be **03/09/2016 12:06 PM** or in other words, 24 hours from now.

Comment: I have provided additional solution using just Excel Worksheet functions (no VBA) and tested it: works fine. Best regards,

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. Best regards,